# How to stop pop/click sound when changing audio within UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a slider that changes audio dependent on its value. It works fine but when the audio is changed, there is a very noticeable pop/clicking sound. Is there any way to get rid of this? This is the set up:

```
@IBAction func audioSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    let sliderValue = Int(sender.value)
    if sliderValue == 1 {
        soundPlayer2.stop()
        soundPlayer3.stop()
        soundPlayer1.play()
        soundPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    else if sliderValue == 2 {
        soundPlayer1.stop()
        soundPlayer3.stop()
        soundPlayer2.play()
        soundPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    else if sliderValue == 3 {
        soundPlayer1.stop()
        soundPlayer2.stop()
        soundPlayer3.play()
        soundPlayer3.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    else if sliderValue == 0 {
        soundPlayer1.stop()
        soundPlayer2.stop()
        soundPlayer3.stop()
    }
}
```

I'm thinking maybe something that delays the start of the next audio?

I have tried using .pause but the pop still happens.

Comment: Just curious: why do you have three players? Have you tried using a single player but changing the soundURL when sliding?

Comment: The user interface part is not relevant for causing clicks. The clicks can be only caused on the real time thread, because there is no integration (=smoothing) of control values' abrupt changes, or if there is a sudden change of audio material, without crossfade or if there are some scheduling problems (blocking on the real time thread, memory management, etc). BTW, what do you mean by _"slider that changes audio dependent on its value"_? Please, post code relevant to your problem.

Comment: Michael - it's because there are sounds that play for each value that the slider is set to. I have tried changing the if statement so that it looks for a different file

User 307- The code is relevant to the problem - read the statement - I don't know how I can make it clearer.

Any smoothing suggestions? Does AVFoundation have a delay feature?